# \href line break issue

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking

I'm running into trouble using \href with a long link diskription which is then broken over two lines. The issue is the link box, which obviously cannot be properly broken and then disappears, as can be seen on the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  \href{url}{Very long link which should be broken}

  \url{Very/long/link/which/should/be/broken}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: sdfsdenter image description here]

As you can see, *breakurl* package creates two frames one for each line, whereas *href* command controlled by *hyperref* package creates only a small frame between the lines. In combination mit colores links without frames, it is almost impossible to find the link by mouse...

**Update:** This issue occures using *latex* + *dvipdf* chain only, *pdflatex* works fine. Ommiting *brakurl* package for *latex* + *dvipdf* results in *url* not broken:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}

\framebox{
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \href{url}{Very long link which should be broken}

    \url{Very/long/link/which/should/be/broken}
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you even use `breakurl`? `hyperref` breaks the first link in a correct way too.

Answer (score 4):

For me your code gives a correct broken url. Probably you are just using a compiler that conflicts with this setup. As @Cupora states `latex+dvipdf` seem to refuse making the right links.

I've compiled with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` and they both show the following output:

[image: links]

`xelatex` seems to fail using `breakurl`, but that may be an issue with my setup.

Comment: This behaviour looks to depend on compiler one is using. *pdflatex* causes no problem, whereas *latex* + *dvipdf* does it. Evenmore, removeing *breakurl* leads to no change on *href* output, but *url* is not broken anymore.

Comment: @Cupora Okay, I usually compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. But as you can see, `\url` is broken here.

Comment: @Cupora The answer is now community wiki, so if you have further ideas just add them.

Comment: Same problem with XeLaTex here.